# handle configuration changes using ConfligChanges in the manifest

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

My app contains two fragments: list fragment, and detail fragment. Everything works fine.But when I change the orientation. everything gets messed up. I tried something like this to change orientation, it works in case of landscape to portrait, but doesn't work in portrait to landscape. Can anyone help me. here is my tried code:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Fragment listfragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.fragment_container);
        Fragment detailfragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.fragment_container2);
        FrameLayout fragmentLayout2;
        fragmentLayout2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container2);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            if (listfragment != null) {
                replaceFragment(listfragment);

            }
            if (detailfragment != null) {
                replaceNewFragment(detailfragment);

            }
        }
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            fragmentLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
}
```

Comment: the are menu item icons in the actionbar that you want to change I guess ?

Comment: yes..I want to change action bar menu  items, when orientation changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onConfigurationChanged on your mainActivity that extends ActionBarActivity for this to work. Something like this should work:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
   getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon_land);//getSupportActionBar() for support library
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon_potrait);
}
}
```

Comment: But activity doesn't get recreated in this right..I want activity to be recreated..

Answer (score 0):

Call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` whenever you want to change the icons in the ActionBar. This'll redraw the ActionBar items and hence make a call to `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. Inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, you can check the orientation and set the respective layout for the menu items or just change the icons.

And since you want to recreate the menu on orientation change, you can call the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method inside `onCreate()` because it will be called when the orientation changes.

Comment: I should call it inside on create of the activity?

Comment: it says it requires API level 11..I'm supporting from api level 9

Comment: API < 11 use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu().

Comment: Also, what's not working ? supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() or the code ?

Comment: i used onCreateOptions menu..I'm using action bar in base activity...not in fragment..I'm just showing/hiding icons while replacing the fragments

Comment: From Android Docs : However, you should use onCreateOptionsMenu() only to create the initial menu state and not to make changes during the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Also, check this out : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu

Comment: but i've been told to use it only from the activity